# What is best approach making Google Home Realtime speaking

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I have an idea of making a live commentary assistant for football matches and so far this is what I have achieved:

I am using Dialogflow and achieved linking it with Actions on Google, so every time I say something Dialogflow can detect and fire an event to google home so the Google home responses.

The thing I would like to know more is, how about for example when a team scores a goal and google assistant catch that instantly, in real time.

One possibility is, I have the API for getting all the matches and scores updated every time team scores and fetch that every second and then call an intent in dialogflow so that will fire to google home assistant, but I am thinking that is somehow not the best idea.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Sorry I am not adding any code, as the code in this case is not important as is the approach, idea how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Actions on Google is not suited for this kind of use-case. The platform is designed for *conversational* experiences, where there's a back and forth. The platform intentionally limits real time features like background continual listening as well as things like push notifications.

[Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) do work on phones, although not other surfaces like smart speakers (ie. Google Home). You can use that to get close to the behavior you may want, but otherwise it may not be suitable for your use case.